# Как удалить коммит слияния после git pull

Tags: git, git-rebase

Добрый день. Представьте 20 разработчиков пушат в master, соответственно история коммитов переполнена сообщениями типа:

> Merge branch 'master'

Я решил что мне поможет:

```
git pull origin master
```

затем делаем еще коммит и затем

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2 // и типа удаляем нужный коммит из истории
```

но rebase не выводит коммит с Merge branch 'master'

Помогите пожалуйста понять что не так делаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://toster.ru/q/53568

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

> но rebase не выводит коммит с Merge branch 'master'

и не должен.

> Помогите пожалуйста понять что не так делаю.

насколько я понимаю вашу цель (убрать коммит слияния из истории данной ветки), вы всё сделали верно для её достижения.

Comment: Да действительно, коммит слияния исчез, а последний коммит остался. Видимо нужно лучше изучить rebase. Благодарю.